# No me funciona setOnItemClickListener de ListView en un Fragement (con pestañas)

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment, android-listview

Estoy implementando un Listview en un fragment (con pestañas), al hacer clip en la lista necesito que me lleve a una actividad, pero para la prueba le aplico un Log en el setOnItemClickListener, pero no responde. qué pude hacer hecho de malo?

mi código (XML):

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  tools:context="com.example.joelii.sinapsis.Consultas.Clientes.BuscarClienteActivity$PlaceholderFragment">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/LsClientesAll"
    tools:listitem="@layout/cardview_buscar_clientes"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

y en el Fragment:

```
public class FragmentBuscarClientesAll extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private ListView LvClientesAll;
private BuscarClientesAdapter adapter;
Context C;
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    C = context;

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BaseDeDatos BD = new BaseDeDatos(C, ContratoBD.DBNAME,null,ContratoBD.DB_VERSION);
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buscar_cliente,container,false);
    LvClientesAll = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.LsClientesAll);

   LvClientesAll.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    List<ClientesClass> ListaRecuperadas = new ArrayList<>();

    //BD.Abrir();
    ListaRecuperadas = BD.ListaClientes();
    //BD.Cerrar();

    if (!(ListaRecuperadas==null)){
        adapter = new BuscarClientesAdapter(ListaRecuperadas,C);
        LvClientesAll.setAdapter(adapter);
    }      


    return v;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.LsClientesAll:
            Log.i(Constantes.TAG,"onItemClick listview");
    }
}
```

}

Log.i(Constantes.TAG,"onItemClick listview"); nunca se ejecuta :(

[image: Al hacer click en la lista debería funcionar]
Al hacer click en la lista debería funcionar

por favor, ayudaa

Comment: Pon el Log.d fuera del switch y dime si te imprime.

Comment: Tampoco me imprime. Lo que imprime es //02-07 13:38:44.117 23486-23486/? I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP ,cada vez que le hago el item click, pero esto ya lo hacia mucho antes de esta prueba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que el TextView de mi CardView tenía este atributo "inpuType:TextMutiline", le quité ese atributo y solución. Debo agradecer a esta página que me trajo la solución: https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/listview-doesnt-respond-to-onitemclicklistener/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]